# I want to create version for every build in visual studio

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, version

So whenever i deploy the changes on server I need to clear the cache on my local system browser to reflect the changes on website. to prevent this in javascript we give version to each and every file so we dont need to clear cache to reflect changes,

> Example: source/file.js?V2

Here we are working with react js(asp.net core Visual studio 2019) with every publish visual  studio 2019 generate the following file

ClientApp(consist of build,js(Bundled JS) css(Bundled css) file)
runtimes
ru-ru
DLLs(application and third party dll)

So how can we give version to every build or file so we don't need to clear cache whenever changes are deployed on server

we working with
**react js,asp.net core visual studio 2019**

Answer (score 2):

Doing that per build doesn't make a lot of sense. What makes more sense it invalidate it if the file was changed. For that people usually append a hash to the url, i.e. `~/js/app.js?v=<hashhere>`.

ASP.NET Core comes with a tag helper which adds and calculates the hash for you, called `asp-append-version`.

```
<script src="~/js/app.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Every time the file is changed, the hashes changes and will result in a different `src` url, forcing the browser to load it from the server rather than caching it